# I am to plot the graph but i am facing problem. Using other variable i am able to plot but using the variable name 'temperature' i am getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxZVu.jpg)i am to plot the graph. Using the variable name 'temperature' i am getting error:

[image: screenshot of Jupyter showing the traceback]

following is my code. and the error i get is `KeyError: 'Temperature'`

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize = (15,10))
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation = 45)

ax1.plot(dates, feature['Wind Speed'])
ax1.set_xlabel(''); ax1.set_ylabel('Wind Speed'); ax1.set_title('Wind Speed')

ax2.plot(dates, feature['Pressure'])
ax2.set_xlabel(''); ax2.set_ylabel('Pressure'); ax2.set_title('Pressure')

ax3.plot(dates, feature['Relative Humidity'])
ax3.set_xlabel('Date'); ax3.set_ylabel('Relative Humidity'); 
ax3.set_title('Relative Humidity')

ax4.plot(dates, feature['Temperature'])
ax4.set_xlabel('Date'); ax4.set_ylabel('Temperature'); 
ax4.set_title('Temperature')

plt.tight_layout(pad=2)
```

Comment: Your `feature` dataframe does not contain a "Temperature" column.

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? What happened when you tried to understand the problem? Did you try anything at all? For example, did you use a search engine to look up words that you don't know in the error message? Did you try to check that your data looks the way you expect it to look? Did you try to look for any differences between the code that works and the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you Karl for your valuable comment but just to make you clear my data frame has the 'temperature' column and I am still getting errors while running.  The following are the variables I have in my data frame: 'Temperature, Wind speed, relative density, air pressure '. Thank you

Comment: Dear KarI, I  have added pictures of my data frame. Can you please help me get rid of this error. Thank you